# Data table creation using Jasper reports

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a data table using Jasper reports. I am using a JRBeanCollectionDataSource to execute the report. Here is the subreport I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Simple bean example" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Table Data Set">
        <field name="phoneNumber" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[phoneNumber]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="phoneType" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[phoneType]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="130" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="0" y="49" width="180" height="50"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Data Set">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phoneType}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phoneNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="239" y="12" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Phone Numbers]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

And the corresponding phone bean is

```
package model;

public class Phone {

    private String phoneType;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Phone() {
    }

    public Phone(String phoneType, String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneType = phoneType;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneType() {
        return phoneType;
    }
    public void setPhoneType(String phoneType) {
        this.phoneType = phoneType;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("\nPhone type: ");
        builder.append(getPhoneType());
        builder.append("\t");
        builder.append("Phone number: ");
        builder.append(getPhoneNumber());
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

When I call JasperFillManager.fillReport, I am getting the following exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : type
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:750)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTableSubreport.prepareSubreport(FillTableSubreport.java:159)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.prepare(FillTable.java:307)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:129)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:393)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:323)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:257)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:644)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : type
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:895)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:860)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:837)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1434)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:648)
```

But I have not defined any field named 'type' in Phone bean. Could not understand why this error is coming up. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the field declaration like this:

```xml
<field name="phoneType" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[phone.phoneType]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Comment: It is working now. But the first row being passed in the collection is not appearing in the table formed.

Comment: This is another issue. You can read [this faq](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html#FAQ20)